# Should I learn Android Studio before making game with libGDX?

Tags: android, android-studio, libgdx

I want to to make an Android game with libGDX but most of the resources that I found on the internet are using Android Studio (I don't know will it help, if I learn libGDX faster and better?), but I like using Netbeans and don't like developing the Android apps so... Can I learn libGDX without spending times for Android Studio? That's all, thanks!

Comment: You don't need to write an android app to use libgdx

Comment: Could you give me more, thanks!

Comment: I don't have more. I am stating a fact. LibGDX is not android specific

Comment: you can use netbeans with libgdx, but I suggest using intellij instead

Comment: You will save countless frustrating hours by using IntelliJ from the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LibGDX is cross-platform game development framework. Either you're developing an Android app or not,  you **should** use Android Studio/ IntellijIDEA<sup>*</sup>. It's the only recommendation.

LibGDX using `gradle` for artifact management but you can also skip `gradle` and manually inject dependent jar in your project but I think It's totally wastage of time. Don't waste your time in project setup or further project management, in fact of you should focus on game logic.

You can also use any other IDE with `gradle` management, but I think Android Studio is good and easy to use. Android Studio doesn't have any rocket science logic, it's quite easy. Only you've spent some times with it, that's all.

*<sub><sub>Both Android Studio or IntellJIDEA has almost same functions, so you can stick with any one.</sub></sub>

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I will think about that!