# Libgdx-Gradle Error at runtime

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx, overlap2d

Recently, I was working on a LibGdx Project when i heard about what overlap2D could manage.. So i tried it out with the gdx jar that i had already (gdx 1.9.6) in third party project i checked only the Overlap2D extention (v 0.1.0). on the video tutorial 
*((This one btw, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bhvHm2sM0qo))* 
i was watch it was asked to get into the build.gradle file and change the overlap lib version to **0.1.1-SNAPSHOT** for all the project.

Before trying that, i tried without doing so, as expected i could not manage to uses all the classes as in the tutorial.

The method `getEngine()` is undefined for the type *SceneLoader*

Since then i tried replacing the line in the build.gradle file. 
I tried a new project to replace the line in the build file just after creating the project.
and even using overlap2D to get Gdx project setup to the right version.

*each time i tried to change the build file gradle could not manage that.*

*each time i tried without changing it i could not use that method.*

**My setup is eclipse IDE Oxygen Release (4.7.0)**

Here's some coding:

```
import [...]

public class overlap extends ApplicationAdapter {
    SceneLoader sl;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        sl = new SceneLoader();
        sl.loadScene("MainScene");

    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        sl.getEngine();
    }
}
```

The error from gradle said he can't find a repo where there is the overlap2d runtime.

Could use some help in here!

Answer (score 0):

Current stable version of `overlap2d-runtime-libgd‌​x` is `0.1.1` so inject artifact in this way :

```
compile "com.underwaterapps.overlap2druntime:overlap2d-runtime-libgd‌​x:0.1.1
```

in your core module of your project as dependency.

If you want to use SNAPSHOT version use :

```
compile "com.underwaterapps.overlap2druntime:overlap2d-runtime-libgdx:0.1.2-SNAPSHOT
```

---

I'll recommend you to use IntelliJIDEA or Android Studio !!! - [why ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44666530/3445320)